# Heard of a deconstructed kernel project?

Tags: kernel

I recall seeing a project for assembling a kernel out of parts that were deliberately factored/deconstructed so as to maximize separation.  Does anyone know of such a project?  It goes without saying I need it to be Open Source.

Comment: Are you talking about a microkernel?

Comment: offtopic, better fit to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

That sounds roughly like a microkernel. Obvious examples that are available for download include [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) and [Mach](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/mach/public/www/mach.html). Note that while CMU no longer develops Mach, it is in active development and use elsewhere (e.g., as the core of Apple's [Darwin](http://www.opensource.apple.com/)).